# Magento2 - How to translate string using js?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3.1, magento2.2.3

Does not translate a string in Arabic(ar_SA) Language, How to translate using `jQuery`?

```
require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/translate"
    ],
    function($,$t) {
        alert($t("hello"));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow below step.

1. Link the mage/translate library:

   `define (['jquery', 'mage/translate'], function ($) {...});`
2. Use the $.mage.__('') function when adding a string:

   `$.mage.__('<string>');`
3. If your string contains a variable, to add a placeholder for this variable to the string stored in the dictionary, use the syntax similar to the following:

   `$.mage.__('Hello %1').replace('%1', yourVariable);`

I hope it helps!

Comment: I have also try this but it's not working any other solution then please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can translate js error message Below way this

```
require([
'jquery', // jquery Library
'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($){ 
    $(window).load(function() {
        alert($.mage.__('hello'));
    });
});
```

> Magento2 use `mage/translate.js` for translation

Comment: I have also tried this but it's not working any other solution then please tell me

Comment: @pankajparmar you have run deploy command? and check this file `pub/static/frontend/Your/Theme/<language>/js-translation.json`

Comment: Have you added your string translation in i18 ar_SA.csv file?

Comment: @ShaileshKatarmal you need to add and then run deploy command and check

Comment: @ShaileshKatarmal yes,I have added string ar_SA.csv then execute all command.

Comment: @ShaileshKatarmal  please check it : https://prnt.sc/r8uupl and reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html